# Good themes with youtube integration

Tags: theming, files

Are there any good themes for drupal which have already been integrated with YouTube?

I have been searching for Drupal themes, but it looks like they are integrated with JWplayer rather than YouTube.

Also are there any video tutorials for YouTube integration in Drupal?

Comment: What do you mean by Youtube integration?  You can embed Youtube videos or use the Media module to handle them; it doesn't matter what your theme is.

Comment: "Are there any good themes for drupal which have already been integrated with Drupal."

Comment: Try to be more specific. A good Theme? Define good. Good looking (always subjective), fast, easy to maintain, ....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many modules that facilitate embedding YouTube videos on your site.  You can also just paste the Embed code where you need to.

Take a look at Media
http://drupal.org/project/media

Embedded Media Field with Media: YouTube extension is also very popular
http://drupal.org/project/emfield
http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube